# updating solidity state in for loop - good idea?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

Is updating solidity state variable in a for loop a good idea?

```
contract Looper {
    uint public totalPeople;
    uint[] public peopleValue;
    
//would this function fail say of the for loop runs for 30,000 times?
    funciton add10() external {
       for(uint i = 0,i<= totalPeople;i++){
          peopleValue[i] = peopleValue[i] + 10;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its going to be very expensive. Try it out in Remix. I have, and running 1000 times cost 1.5 million gas. Gotta find a better way

Comment: Might want to take a look at this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/solidity-gas-optimisation-for-loops?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends very much on your contract. Besides the comments mentioned about the gas costs being very high, this actually can be used in some cases for a Denial of Service attack on a contract.

Your contract might stop working if the amount of `totalPeople` is too high.

A malicious party could register so many people that iterating all the registered people would always require more gas than available in a block (current max is ~30 million gas per block).

More details for this can be founds here: https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/attacks/denial-of-service/#dos-with-block-gas-limit

Comment: So using loops might almost fail most of the times. is there any situations where we can use it effectively? Like to automatically transfer ethers or to update state in loop? or any other situations?

Comment: You can still safely use loops if you know how many iterations there will be, or if you make it an "optional" loop.

Answer (score 0):

Does this apply to your question?

https://github.com/wissalHaji/solidity-coding-advices/blob/master/best-practices/be-careful-with-loops.md

Im trying to figure it out how make external calls inside loops, or dont